# c++ variadic templates, arguments descendants of same base class

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Consider the following base interface and two concrete implementations of it. I would like to test these with 1 template method, with arguments that are the types to be tested. All the sub-types (QueueA, QueueB) inherit from IQueue. How could I achieve an implementation for the template method tester_queues? Similar functionality can be achieved by passing in a std::vector of instances of the classes, and would be easier. I am just curious if something like what is described in method tester_queues is possible to achieve.

```
template<class T>
class IQueue
{
protected:
    T Data[10];
public:
    virtual const T pop()          = 0;
    virtual void     push(const T&) = 0;
};

template<class T>
class QueueA : public IQueue<T>
{
    const T pop() final {
        std::cout << "pop queue A" << std::endl;
        return T{};
    }

    void push(const T& aItemRef) final {
        std::cout << "PUSH queue A" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class T>
class QueueB : public IQueue<T>
{
    const T pop() final {
        std::cout << "pop queue B" << std::endl;
        return T{};
    }

    void push(const T& aItemRef) final {
        std::cout << "PUSH queue B" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class T>
void test_push_pop(IQueue<T>* aQueueP)
{
    aQueueP->push();
    aQueueP->pop();
};


template<class ... ARGS>
void tester_queues()
{
    // unpack ARGS
    // construct objects of each type into in a vector
    // std::vector<IQueue*> vec = { ARGS... };
    // then execute test_push_pop for each
    // std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](IQueue* itemP) {
    //      test_push_pop(itemP);
    // });
};


int main()
{
    tester_queues<QueueA<int>,
                  QueueB<char>>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reasdon you want `tester_queues<QueueA<int>, QueueB<char>>();` instead of `tester_queues(QueueA<int>{}, QueueB<char>{});`?

Comment: @NathanOliver just curious like said in the question title

Comment: I don't think this is possible. There is nothing as a pointer-to-template `IQueue*`. For each template argument, classes form a separate and non-related class hierarchy.

Comment: @DanielLangr it is possible, see my answer

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sure, this way. But you skipped that vector part, which would add runtime dependency. Don't know how important is that for OP though.

Comment: @DanielLangr I intentionally omitted the "vector part" because the OP was already aware of `vector` as an alternative but wasn't asking for a `std::vector` solution here, only how to make `tester_queues<QueueA<int>, QueueB<char>>()` work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to specify only the Queue types as template arguments, then you can use something like this to let `tester_queues()` construct instances of those type internally for testing:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class IQueue
{
protected:
    T Data[10];
public:
    virtual const T pop()          = 0;
    virtual void    push(const T&) = 0;
};

template<class T>
class QueueA : public IQueue<T>
{
public:
    const T pop() final {
        std::cout << "pop queue A" << std::endl;
        return T{};
    }

    void push(const T& aItemRef) final {
        std::cout << "PUSH queue A" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class T>
class QueueB : public IQueue<T>
{
public:
    const T pop() final {
        std::cout << "pop queue B" << std::endl;
        return T{};
    }

    void push(const T& aItemRef) final {
        std::cout << "PUSH queue B" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class... Ts>
struct Tester;

template <class T, class... Ts>
struct Tester<T, Ts...>
{
    template<class U>
    static void test_push_pop(IQueue<U>&& aQueueP)
    {
        aQueueP.push(U{});
        aQueueP.pop();
    }

    static void test_push_pops()
    {
        test_push_pop(T{});
        Tester<Ts...>::test_push_pops();
    }
};

template<>
struct Tester<>
{
    static void test_push_pops() {}
};

template<class... Ts>
void tester_queues()
{
    Tester<Ts...>::test_push_pops();
};

int main()
{
    tester_queues< QueueA<int>, QueueB<char> >();
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/mJIJX6)

Alternatively, you can construct your own objects of the desired types and then pass them into `tester_queues()` as input parameters, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<class T>
class IQueue
{
protected:
    T Data[10];
public:
    virtual const T pop()          = 0;
    virtual void    push(const T&) = 0;
};

template<class T>
class QueueA : public IQueue<T>
{
public:
    const T pop() final {
        std::cout << "pop queue A" << std::endl;
        return T{};
    }

    void push(const T& aItemRef) final {
        std::cout << "PUSH queue A" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class T>
class QueueB : public IQueue<T>
{
public:
    const T pop() final {
        std::cout << "pop queue B" << std::endl;
        return T{};
    }

    void push(const T& aItemRef) final {
        std::cout << "PUSH queue B" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class T>
void test_push_pop(IQueue<T>& aQueueP)
{
    aQueueP.push(T{});
    aQueueP.pop();
}

void test_push_pops()
{
}

template<class T, class... Ts>
void test_push_pops(T&& aQueueP, Ts&&... aQueuePs)
{
    test_push_pop(std::forward<T>(aQueueP));
    test_push_pops(aQueuePs...);
};

template<class... Ts>
void tester_queues(Ts&&... args)
{
    test_push_pops(args...);
};

int main()
{
    tester_queues( QueueA<int>{}, QueueB<char>{} );
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/NBERCu)